# signature verification using node.js crypto and aws s3 returns error wrong tag

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, node-crypto

Trying to validate a signature of a file using Node.js Crypto.  Not getting success.  I'm new to Node.js.
this openSSL works for me:

```
openssl enc -d -A -base64 -in update.sig -out update.sha256 - that turns the sig into a binary
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify PublicKey.pem -signature update.sha256 update.zip
```

however when I attempt to implement that in Node.js it's not working.
I am storing the signature file (update.sig) and the file that is signed (update.zip) and the public key from the keypair used in generating the signature (publicKey.pem) in aws s3.  This is the node.js code snippet which is not working

```
    Key = path + "update." + uid + ".sig"
    console.log("Looking for " + Key)
    var signature = await s3.getObject({Bucket, Key }).promise();
    var binSignature = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(signature.Body).digest()
    console.log("signature: ", signature)
    
    Key = path + "update." + uid + ".zip"
    console.log("Looking for " + Key)
    var data = await s3.getObject({Bucket, Key} ).promise();
    console.log("data: ", data)
    
    Key = "PublicKey.pem"
    console.log("Looking for " + Key)
    var pemKey = await s3.getObject({Bucket, Key}).promise();
    console.log("pemKey: ", pemKey)
    
    var verified = crypto.verify("sha256", data.Body, pemKey.Body, binSignature.Body)
    console.log("verified: ", verified)
```

returns

```
2022-01-25T14:09:32.478Z    d7054eef-8e81-4dfa-bb58-7b5165149202    INFO    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "signature" argument must be an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
    at Object.verifyOneShot [as verify] (internal/crypto/sig.js:212:11)
    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/app.js:111:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

If I use the signature directly from the file, rather than converting it to a binary with the crypto.createHash('sha256'), I get this failure

```
2022-01-25T13:57:46.055Z    19b11d30-c714-4f20-b7af-fa6d112c1486    INFO    Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
    at Object.verifyOneShot [as verify] (internal/crypto/sig.js:219:10)
    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/app.js:109:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error'
  ],
  library: 'asn1 encoding routines',
  function: 'asn1_check_tlen',
  reason: 'wrong tag',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_ASN1_WRONG_TAG'
}
```

The openSSL commands above verify these successfully.
signature looks like this

```
MGYCMQCrK8FzAq2Fl+CVAWVQLOBNtNf0o+Ylwo/at4GZQtdu/UAL2yQijdNzPcEK/sIevngCMQDNOVQ0TWWyoBx2cTRgBxsaUd8jR8qIE5T9YrO81i4bARHALTQIMQNWNvyanyghAlE=
```

publicKey.pem looks like this

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEQ0UK86Jdls1MT6iAVSrFuI+N2dU5wHXQ
fyHga2BDq+O9reM47KpfQR1pF/+MPsWf8IH8Il8HkIDhizAjMsSR3fwSe5xKns02
lJm71a3pY1+AFx3wbc1GP57X6vKFNJPm
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: The 1st OpenSSL statement merely performs a Base64 decoding, i.e. _update.sig_ apparently contains a Base64 encoded signature. This must be Base64 decoded in NodeJS presumably. How this is done depends on the type of `signature.Body`. If this is a Base64 encoded string, e.g. with `Buffer.from("...", "base64")`. Creating a hash with `crypto.createHash('sha256')` seems wrong to me, since `crypto.verify()` actually does this implicitly. Sample data would simplify troubleshooting.

Comment: I was handed a signature file 'update.sig' a public key .pem file and a zip file 'update.zip' and asked to verify the signature. Thought it would be simply feeding the three into a verifier in node.js but not so....

Comment: I tried adding a base64 decode on the signature using this   
const decodedSignature = Buffer.from(signature.Body, 'base64');   
and gave that to the verifier but it still fails

Comment: Assuming that `data.Body`, `pemKey.Body` and `signature.Body` are buffers that contain the binary message, the PEM key and the binary signature, the verification on my machine with `crypto.verify(...)` is successful in accordance with the OpenSSL statement and the problem is not reproducible. If you still have problems, please post complete sample data and the current code used.